# Running migration via code. The classes in the module cannot be loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, mono, identity

The Problem, *The classes in the module cannot be loaded.*

So some background, I'm trying to prove that it is possible to run ASP.NET C# MVC 5.1 Website using the latest tech, EF6 / ASP.NET Identity, without the dependancy on Microsoft Architecture. I.E. Mono.

Thus far the MVC stuff is working 100%. So started to implement entity framework. As I'm using Xamarin studio I have no access to the package manager console.
Following this [guide](http://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/) I have tried to essentially run `Update-Database` but upon running the code the extreamly unhelpful error: "*The classes in the module cannot be loaded.*"

Given the complications of a project like this I'm willing to grant github access to anyone should they want to test the full code themselves.

**Code to run Update**

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new MySqlInitializer());
var configuration = new Configuration();
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration); //The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
migrator.Update();
```

**Configuration.cs**

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
    private MyDbContext _context;

    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());

        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

    static MyDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
    }

    public MyDbContext() : base("MyDbContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var value = base.SaveChanges();
        return value;
    }
}
```